# Showing files from multiple directories which all have different file names and display in table PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to display a list of files in 3 separate directories. I have it working if all the file names are the same in each folder it works fine. However, if the filename is different in the first folder, the images don't display in the other two. So all filenames have to be the same but I need it so it doesn't matter if the filenames are the same or not.

Here's what I have so far.

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$dirname = "dir1";
$dirnameTwo = "dir2";
$dirnameThree = "dir3";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv='refresh' content='10'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='max-age=0' />
    <meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache' />
    <meta http-equiv='expires' content='0' />
    <meta http-equiv='expires' content='Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT' />
    <meta http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache' />
</head>
<html>

<body>
<style type="text/css">
    .pi-title {
        padding: 1rem;
    }
</style>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="pi-title">
            <h3>Test</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="table-container col-md-12">
            <table class="table" border='1' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='0' bordercolor='#ccc'>
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">ID</th>
                    <th scope="col">File Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">PI 1</th>
                    <th scope="col">PI 2</th>
                    <th scope="col">PI 3</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr></tr>
                <tr>
                    <?php
                    array_multisort(array_map('filemtime', ($files = glob("*.*"))), SORT_DESC, $files);
                    $directories = implode(',', [ $dirname, $dirnameTwo, $dirnameThree]);
                    $files = glob("./{{$directories}}/*", GLOB_BRACE);
                    $i = 1;
                    foreach($files as $filename) {
                      if (file_exists($filename)) {
                            echo "</tr>";
                            echo "<td><font face='Arial' size='6'>$i</font></td>";
                            echo "<td><font face='Arial' size='6' color='red'>" . date ("F d Y H:i", filemtime($filename));
                            echo "</font></td>";
                        }
                        print("

                           <td><img src='$filename' height='180' width='220'></td>
                           <td><img src='$filename' height='180' width='220'></td>
                           <td><img src='$filename' height='180' width='220'></td>

                           ");
                        $i++;
                        if($i==13) break;
                    }
                    ?>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are very unclear in your description. You have three colums, each for one subfolder. Equal file *names* does not have to mean equal *images*. Creation/modification time stamps are different for each equal named file in different folders. There can be (not necessarily) duplicate names. My solution handles single files containing the path, so `dir1/file1` and `dir2/file1` are different. You should be much more clear what you actually are trying to achieve and how to display in different cases.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to have 3 folders (dir/dir2/dir3) and in the root have a main index.php file to show the contents (images) of each folder in a table. So each column will have dir/image1 dir2/image1 dir3/image1 etc... Which then stops looping at 12

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `GLOB_BRACE` flag:

```
$directories = implode(',', [ $dirname, $dirnameTwo, $dirnameThree]);
$files = glob("./{{$directories}}/*", GLOB_BRACE);
```

`glob('{dir1,dir2}/*', GLOB_BRACE)` gives you a list of all files in both folders, `dir1` and `dir2`. In string interpolations curly braces around variables have a special meaning, thus you need double braces which result in single braces after interpolation.

Comment: Would I add to the top where I have defined the variable $dirname/$dirnameTwo/$dirnameThree?

Comment: @Nathe You can define immediately `$dirnames = ['folder1', 'folder2', 'folder3'];` and implode or even `directories = 'folder1,folder2,folder3';` What you finally want to get is a pattern like `'./{dir1,dir2,dir3}/*'`

Comment: I've got it with the correct path but the images are not showing because it's showing the directory path twice? Once It's showing once it will work

Comment: I've got this before the foreach loop
 glob('', GLOB_BRACE);
 $directories = implode(',', ['./dir1/', './dir2/', './dir3/']);
$files = glob("{{$directories}}/*", GLOB_BRACE);

Then in the loop $dirname$filename but shows the path twice?

Comment: `src='$dirname$filename'` The path is already included in $filename. Try out `var_dump(glob(...))`

Comment: Thanks for the help so far mate, I've updated the original post with my current code. It still shows the path twice, but once once if I do a var dump?

Comment: @Nathe `src='$dirname$filename'` hasn't changed, still extra `$dirname` present.

Comment: It's not showing 2 paths now which is good. However, it's showing only folder one?

Comment: @Quasimodos-clone I've updated the original post with the changes. The images all show, but they all show from dir1 only. For example, ./dir1/image.jpg and where it should say ./dir2/image.jpg, it shows the same as the first one (./dir1/image.jpg)